# DataTable array into DataSet

Tags: xml, datatable, dataset

I'm creating an application that is supposed to work a little like ASCII - you put in a code and it loads a matrix of booleans which are the graphic representation of the character whose code it was.
I need to be able to save into it and to edit it - therefore I thought of using xml (I'm supposed to be able to load from it to another application).
All these mean I should have an array of tables, which are arranged in the same way, and could be reached  by an index.
The thing is - I'm not really familiar enough with datasets to know if this could work.
Can I address dataset[135].[5][7]?
Can I change it that way?
Am I on the right way about it at all?